# Hadoop - What happens when multiple processes try to write to the same file at the same time?

Tags: hadoop

What happens when multiple processes try to write to the same file at the same time? Is it even possible? Is there some kind of buffering?

Comment: don't forget that once a file exists in HDFS, it is read (or delete) - only

Comment: @climbage didn't notice that in the API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`hadoop fs -put` and writing files to HDFS via the API are atomic. One write will fail because the file already exists and the other one will write out its contents.

Comment: but what if I am  trying to append to an existing file simultaneously from two different processes?

Comment: HDFS does not support that. But... WHY?? Would you append to an existing file on your local file system with two processes?? No! It's near impossible to guarantee the order of the bytes being appended, so you won't get clean record boundaries... it'll just all be mixed together and corrupted.

Comment: append is possible http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html   What I want to ask - is there some sort of local buffering of the append request, so that one append happens after the other?

Comment: I wasn't saying HDFS doesn't support append... sorry for not being clear. It does. But, you are suppose to handle coordination at the application level.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a scientific opinion or not, but I personally don't "trust" append. It's had a lot of problems in the past. I definitely prefer to write new files.